# return a number between 3 to 5 by get a number between 1 until 10000!

Tags: algorithms, education

I want  to have a math math formulas to do this operation:

A:get a number between 1 to 10000
B:reteun a number between 3.00 until 5 for example 3.89

for greater number return greater number too!

A:500 ---> 3.45
B:9000 ---> 4.70
C:10000 -->5

can anybody help me? I need it for a php algorithm.

Comment: Do you need these specific values for $f(500)$, $f(9000)$ and $f(10000)$?

Comment: value of f(500) = 3.45 just is an example...in general yes...I want value of f(x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution might be $f(x) = \frac{x}{5000}+3$.

Comment: simple and great solution...thanks